# Sql group result using key

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't not how to say what i need to do in programing lang. This is my request

```
SELECT pl.id_product, CONCAT( pl.name, ' ', al.name ) AS produkt, al.id_attribute, com.id_product_attribute
FROM ps_stock_available stock
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON pl.id_product = stock.id_product
LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute_combination com ON stock.id_product_attribute = com.id_product_attribute
LEFT JOIN ps_attribute_lang al ON al.id_attribute = com.id_attribute
LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute pa ON ( stock.id_product_attribute = pa.id_product_attribute )
WHERE pl.id_lang =1
AND al.id_lang =1
ORDER BY pl.id_product
```

And this is result
[image: http://s6.ifotos.pl/img/Screensho_exsxssh.png]

This is possible to print

Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts S Orange

Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts S Blue

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: BTW, "LEFT JOIN x WHERE x" is the same as INNER JOIN

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need to print product name and product attribute in my example this is size and color. This attribute is grouping in  com.id_product_attribute. I looking for group this and concat witch product name. Look on screenshot and example how print need look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could use a a **`GROUP_CONCAT`** function on `al.name`, and then concatenate the result from that with `pl.name`.

Something like this:

```
 CONCAT(pl.name,' ',
   GROUP_CONCAT(al.name  ORDER BY al.id_attribute SEPARATOR ' ')
 ) AS produkt
```

To do that, you'd also need to add a **`GROUP BY`** clause to the query (immediately preceding or in place of, the ORDER BY), for example:

```
 GROUP BY pl.id_product, com.id_product_attribute
```

That will effectively "collapse" the rows, so the query would return:

```
id_produkt  produkt                               id_product_attribute 
----------  ------------------------------------- --------------------
         1  Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts S Orange                     1
         1  Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts S Blue                       2
```

(That's assuming that pl.name is returning the **`"Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts"`** portion, and the al.name is returning (e.g.) the **`"S"`** and **`"Orange"`** portions.)

With those changes to the query, if you also return `al.id_attribute` in the SELECT list, then MySQL will return the value of that column from only a single row in the group. To get all of the values returned as a comma separated list, you could again use the **`GROUP_CONCAT`** function in the SELECT list, e.g.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(al.id_attribute ORDER BY al.id_attribute) AS id_attribute_list
```

Comment: You now what i need to do. I first time building big sql query and using concat. In your sql i have error 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP CONCAT(al.name SEPARATOR ' ' ORDER BY al.id_attribute)) AS produkt FROM ps' at line 2

Comment: i have found error you wrote GROUP CONCAT you missed underscore